# android: align a button to the rightmost in XML

Tags: android, alignment

I want to align a button to the rightmost part of the screen, but I am not able to do that.
I am not able to use the **alignParentRight** field here. Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day_of_the_week"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/arrow_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What should I do? How do I fix this?

Comment: if any of the answer helped you mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` as the base layout. And then you'll be able to achieve what you want.

**(i.e)** - `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to keep using your linearLayout, have you tried adding

```
 android:gravity="right"
```

to your button?

as in

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/day_of_the_week"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/arrow_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_right"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Relative layout` it will solve like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use relative layout    
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day_of_the_week"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/arrow_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_right"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```